# System.Drawing namespace can't be used in Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, system.drawing

I've put together a c# console app that runs a web service intending to download a simple pdf document. I can return the object however I can't seem to be able to figure out how to save the pdf object to file.

```
ServiceName.ImageResponse responseObject = Response.GetDocument(12345);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(responseObject.Document);
//System.Drawing is the problem (namespace can't be used in a Web Service)
System.Drawing.Image Img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
Img.Save("c:\\saved.JPG");
```

This is not compiling as I'm receiving (a red squiqly line under System.Drawing and)  the following error:

*Error  1   The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx states the following:

*Caution noteCaution
Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.*

I would simply like to know if there is another way. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can you better describe the error? Compilation? Runtime? What exception? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: @mwilson: Still investigating, but it does compile.

Comment: Are you sure `System.Drawing` is referenced? By default, I don't think it is a default reference in a console app, you might have to manually reference it.

Comment: (to answer both questions in the above comments:) (1)This is not compiling as (2) I'm receiving (a red squiqly line under System.Drawing and) the following error: *The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trebuchet is probably correct. Check to make sure that you have actually done the work of adding a reference to the required dll. Namespaces do not have a 1 to 1 correspondence to .dll files, for what it is worth.

As to this:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use
>   within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes
>   from within one of these application types may produce unexpected
>   problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time
>   exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging
>   Components.

I don't know for certain, but my guess is that several of the components within the System.Drawing namespace expect the process to have access to a [window station](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the desktop, etc., which is where you would see run-time exceptions. I'd take a punt and see if it works (once you've fixed your compilation error). What they're really saying here is "don't call us if this breaks" :)

Comment: Credit to trebuchet. Simply manually add the reference to System.Drawing.